# How to save pbtxt and pb for Google Cloud with the file limit restriction?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have a trained model in Tensorflow and already saved the pb (500mb) and pbtxt (1.5gb), however Google Cloud file limit is 250mb. Does someone that have solved this issue can guide me on how to reduce the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization) to reduce the size of the model (which can bring it down to 25% of its original size). Basically this switches from using floating point to using 8-bit integers.